# Context doesn`t send to the render_to_string Python/Django

Tags: python, django

hi guys I have a Django view that I want to filter my products with ajax(Js) and I think u know that I need to show the products to template too! I`m using render to string Function which gets a template name and a context(dictionary) and return the string of the template , now my problem is my , idk why but my context is not sending to the template , if u have ever used Pycharm u know that for example when u map a template , if every thing is ok it will shows the template icon in the left near the line number! and every things is ok for me but still context doesn`t send :( , i should say that I have a for loop in my template and I think u Know that too , when u click on your for loop context it will move you to the context in view but for me it shows "Cannot find the Declaration" ill write my codes , and ill be thankful if u guys help me :D ( and I have tried context: {"asd": asd} , {"asd": asd} every methods for a

```
template:

{% for product in products %}
    something...
{% empty %}
    if products doesnt exist...
{% endfor %}


views:

def filter_products(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        categories = request.GET.getlist("category")
        products = Product.objects.all().order_by("-created_at").distinct()

        if len(categories) > 0:
            products = Product.objects.filter(category__name=categories).order_by("-     created_at").distinct()

        data = render_to_string("core/async/product-list.html", context={"products": products})
        print(data)
        return JsonResponse({"data": data, "bool": True})
    return redirect("home_app:main")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys i solved the problem myself :D , and the problem was the products doesnt send to the context (as i said before) and why it doesnt send? because in products variable that i have a filter queryset i gave categories to the category__name filter , and category__name just receive one thing not tuple list and ... , and if u noticed , my categories variable is a request.GET.getlist ! its getting list , and for giving a list to a filter u have to do this :
category__name__in (add an "__in" after the category name) and just this !

products = Product.objects.filter(category__name__in=categories).order_by("-created_at").distinct()